# Automatic Hyperlinking of Journal Name in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, urls, hyperlink

I'm trying to solve a problem that I am yet to find a simple elegant solution for in all the posts in this forum. In short, I want the bibliography of a thesis to have clickable hyperlinks on the name of the journal, volume and page numbers (or alternatively the title). This should be done automatically based on the url/doi given in the Bibtex entry.

As this is a thesis, there are hundreds of references, so manually inserting a \href command is not a good solution.

To be clear, the style of reference that I would need is like that used in Physical Review journals. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Instead, the current way the thesis bibliography is formatted gives a separate url and text saying [Online]. Available:

[image]

For the record, here is the current formatting for the bibliography

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}
```

This seems to be a common problem, but not well solved on this forum for Bibtex. Is there really no solution for Bibtex? Many thanks for all the help!

Comment: It depends on the style, so provide a small but complete example so that one can test and check the bbl output. (With biblatex it would be rather easy).

Comment: Thanks. The style is in the original post. Here is a sample entry:

`@article{Hu_2017,
  title = {{Atom Interferometry with the Sr Optical Clock Transition}},
  author = {Hu, Liang and Poli, Nicola and Salvi, Leonardo and Tino, Guglielmo M.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {119},
  issue = {26},
  pages = {263601},
  numpages = {5},
  year = {2017},
  month = {December},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.263601},
  url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.263601}
}`

Comment: a complete example should also contain a small  tex document. Also don't add that in a comment, edit your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE..., you have to do proper tagging in .bib file, then only able to meet the requirement.